# Ping multiple IP Addresses in parallel - C#

Tags: c#, ping

I created an application to ping multiple specific IP Addresses in the Network at the same time  , display a green PictureBox if the ping succeded and red PictureBox if failed. For that i used this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable pingResults = new DataTable();
    pingResults.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                new DataColumn("IP", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Message",typeof(string))});
    try
    {
        pingResults.Clear();
        List<string> ipAddress = new List<string>();
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.1");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.2");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.100");

        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + i, true)[0]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ipAddress.Count; i++)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());

            pictureBoxList[i].BackColor = (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This code works but it takes too long time. I tried a lot of examples here at stackoverflow using BackgroundWorker but i didn't get how to do it

Comment: Why do you `Thread.Sleep`? Also, if you want them to be called in parallel instead of sequentially, you need to either start some Tasks or use [Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Look at `SendPingAsync` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: where is your attempt to ping multiple addresses **at the same time** ?

Comment: Use `SendPingAsync` and place the result into an array/list and call `await Task.WhenAll(list)`.  That will perform in parallel without wasting a thread like `Parallel.xxx` will

Comment: i will edit my post

Comment: **Pro tip:** don't do `catch (Exception ex) { }` as you won't know if you  have a problem or not, particularly when you are still experimenting

Comment: I don't think you want to wait for the tasks on this thread: it's the UI thread, isn't it, so you'll hang the UI until all of the pings are complete I think. You probably want to kick off each ping as a background task and .ContinueWith some code to update the UI (via Dispatcher.Invoke, since we're now on the wrong thread to do that) with the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# how to ping multiple ip adresses at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119344/c-sharp-how-to-ping-multiple-ip-adresses-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Please note that you need to DIspose Ping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, i used the backgroundworker:

```
DataTable pingResults = new DataTable();

List<string> ipAddress = new List<string>();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        pingResults.Clear();
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.1");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.2");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.3");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.4");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.5");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.100");

        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + i, true)[0]);
        }

        Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), (i, loopState) =>
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());

            this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                pictureBoxList[i].BackColor = (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            });

        });
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try Parallel.For, it's simple.

```
Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count() - 1, (i, loopState) =>
{
  Ping ping = new Ping();
  PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());
  //for wpf
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
  {    
    pictureBoxList[i].BackColor = (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;    
  });
  //for winform
  SetColor(pictureBoxList[i], pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
});
//for winform delegate
delegate void SafeSetColor(PictureBox pb, bool success);
private void SetColor(PictureBox pb, bool success)
{
 if(pb.InvokeRequired)
 {
   SafeSetColor objSet=new SafeSetColor(SetColor);
   pb.Invoke(objSet,new object[]{pb, success});
 }
 else
 {
   pb.BackColor = (success) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
 }
}
```

Comment: How about the 'i' ? should i put this code in For loop?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I don't notice pictureBoxList need index. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry but Dispatcher isn't recognized

Comment: It's [System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher). You do need it to update the UI from background threads.

Comment: However I'd guess that this answer will still block the UI thread until all of the parallel pings are complete.

Comment: Just like @Rup says, because updating UI, so use Dispatcher to work in UI thread.

Comment: I update the answer for winform, Dispatcher is for WPF.